# How to subscribe (or not!) to an observable depending of the result of another observable

Tags: angular, rxjs-observables

With angular 10, in a service I have the method getCurrentUser() that makes an http call to my api to return the current user as observable (with one of the property is "isAdmin:boolean"), and I have this other service where I would like to create the method getAllUsers that would return the list of all users (user[]) also as observable but only if the current user is an admin (user.isAdmin = true). I tried a few stuff with rxjs operators like map, switchMap and flatMap but I can feel that I a am completly mistaken, could you give some hints for this?

Here is what I tried in the second service:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root",
})
export class BackofficeService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) {}

    public getAllUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
        this.userService.getCurrentUser().pipe(
            map((user: User) => {
                if (user.roles.includes("admin")) {
                    return this.http.get<User[]>("/api/settings/users/all");
                } else throw new Error("User not admin.");
            })
        );
    }
}
```

I also don't know how to manage the return of getAllUsers() since sometimes it won't return anything if user is not admin. With the simple "else throw new Error()" I got a compiler error because I declared that getAllUsers() should return an Observable.

And then in my component I do:

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-users",
    templateUrl: "./users.component.html",
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {
  public usersList: User[];
  constructor(private boService: BackofficeService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
    this.boService
      .getAllUsers()
      .subscribe((users?: User[]) => {
        if(users){
          this.usersList = users;
        }
      })
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some of what you tried with the rxjs operators?

Comment: I edited the post with what I tried, thanks for your concern!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the precedent post answered my question, I post here another answer that worked for me: I have been told that the good conception in this case is to make the admin logic in a guard, and in the routing for the component using the backoffice service to add this guard.
Works well and seems good practice.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to return null if the user is not admin, by decoupling the two calls (getAdmin() and getAllUsers()).

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: "root",
})
export class BackofficeService {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private userService: UserService) {}

    public getAdmin(): Observable<User> {
        return this.userService.getCurrentUser().pipe(
            map((user: User) => {
                if (user.roles.includes("admin")) {
                    return user;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            })
        );
    }
    
    public getAllUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
        return this.http
            .get<User[]>("/api/settings/users/all").pipe(
            map((users: User[]) => users);
    }
}
```

And then subscribe to both in component, the second only if the first gives the expected result:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.boService
      .getAdmin()
      .subscribe((user: User) => {
        if (user) {
          this.boService
            .getAllUsers()
            .subscribe((users: User[]) => {
              console.log(users);
            });
        }
      });
  }
```

One mistake you made is to place the return not on the Observable but on the Observable result.

Comment: I tried something like this but I thought as best practice that we shouldn't subscribe an observable inside another observable subscription but use operators instead

Answer (score 0):

```
this.service.getUser().pipe(
  switchMap(user => user.isAdmin
    ? this.service.getAllUsers().pipe(users => [user, users])
    : of([user])
  )
).subscribe(([user, users]) => ... ) // users will be undefined if not admin
```